# Nested for loop in java to print the following

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

How would i print the following in Java:

```
  5
 55
555
 55
  5
```

using just nested for loop with no if statements.

What i have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {

        for(int k = 3; k > i; k--) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(int k = 3; k < i; k++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(int j = i; j > 0; j--) {

            System.out.print("5");
        }

        System.out.println();

    }

}
```

As you can see, I got the spaces correct but not the number of `5`'s on each line yet.
I somehow feel that there must be possible to use just 1 for loop for all the spaces?

Comment: @Kayaman This looks more like a brain teaser than homework because of the "no `if` statements" requirement.

Comment: @arshajii you forget nested loop xD

Comment: `for(;;){ System.out.println("5 55 555 55 5"); break; }`

Comment: @nachokk I guess you could just wrap that statement in a nested loop that performs a single iteration.

Comment: @nachokk:  Eh.  `for (int i = 0; i == 0; ++i) { for (int j = 0; j == 0; ++j) { System.out.println("5 55 555 55 5"); } }`  :)

Comment: Had a problem to get it show right on here.. it would not accept space and new line too well.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight If it's a brainteaser, why is he asking it here. We don't need to get our brains teased. It could also be an interview question, another thing we don't need to answer.

Comment: @Kayaman Brain teasers and interview questions are fair game here, assuming that they have to do with coding. OP's only mistake is his failure to provide what he has tried. Even the silliest attempt would be enough to have his question answered.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Looks like he's even posted what he's tried now. I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

You want the number of spaces you print to decrease up to a point and then start increasing again, so one option is to use `abs()`:

```
int n = 3;  // number of columns

for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n - 1; i++) {
    int k = Math.abs(n - i - 1);

    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        System.out.print(' ');

    for (int j = 0; j < n - k; j++)
        System.out.print('5');

    System.out.println();
}
```

```
  5
 55
555
 55
  5
```

Here, `k` is the number of spaces we want to print (hence `n-k` is the number of `5`s, as can be seen in the second `for`-loop). `k` decreases as `i` approaches `n - 1`, at which point it becomes `0`. As `i` increases further, the term inside `abs()` becomes increasingly negative meaning that its absolute value begins growing again.

Comment: `Math.abs` is a hidden conditional ;-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It's possible to implement `abs` without any conditionals. If the OP wanted to avoid *every* conditional, he could do this and the approach would be the same.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Come to think of it, even `println()` will, somewhere along the line, use an `if`. Not to mention the `for`-loops themselves have conditions.

Comment: Judging by the OP's attempt (that's actually only a step away from success) that's not what he meant.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Well, all he says is *"using just nested for loop with no if statements"*, and I don't think this answer violates that.

Comment: I agree with you that your answer fits the letter of the question 100%: OP asked for a solution without an `if`, and here it is - a working solution without an `if`. Moreover, I would prefer a solution based on `abs` in a production environment, because it is much easier to read. However, from OP's attempt it looks to me that he wanted to avoid the obvious conditionals in his code, not only the `if`s, for the same reason he's avoiding the `? :` operator.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Sure, I understand what you're saying. I'll leave this answer up anyway in case it can be useful to the OP (or anyone else who stumbles upon this question).

Answer (score 0):

You need to first break the pattern in two parts :

- Upper Half

  ```
    5
   55
  555
  ```
- Lower Half

  ```
  55
   5
  ```

In upper half there are 3 rows to be printed. Analyze each row.

1. For row no. 1 there are 2 blanks and 1 "5".
2. For row no. 2 there is 1 blank space and 2 "5"s.
3. For row no. 3 there is no blank space and 3 "5"s.

So if i represents my rows then when i is 1 i.e. row no. 1 no. of blank spaces to be printed is (3-i) i.e. 2 and no. of "5"s to be printed is i i.e. 1.

On similar lines you can break the complete problem.
**Solution:**

```
    class Main{
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            for(int i=1;i<=3;i++) {
               for(int j=1;j<=(3-i);j++) {
                   System.out.print(" ");
               }
               for(int j=1;j<=i;j++) {
                   System.out.print("5");
               }
               System.out.println();
            }
            for(int i=1;i<3;i++) {
               for(int j=1;j<=i;j++) {
                   System.out.print(" ");
               }
               for(int j=1;j<=(3-i);j++) {
                   System.out.print("5");
               }
               System.out.println();
            } 
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 1 for loop for the number of rows and a 2nd one for the number of columns. In this way you will need to use 4 for loop ..